# Cannot start Rails Server, "no such file to load -- bundler/setup"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
var/www/amidev/config/boot.rb:6:in `require': no such file to load -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /var/www/amidev/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:5:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

I have got the following error and cannot find solution to fix it ?

Please advise.

Answer (score 17):

You need to install the `bundler` gem.

To do that, just run `gem install bundler` and try again.

Comment: Try `cd`ing into the project folder and running `bundle install`. What happens?

Comment: I have updated the ruby to the latest head version then rung bundle install. After that it start working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are executing whatever command you are executing here with "bundle exec".

For instance:

```
bundle exec rake -T
```

instead of:

```
rake -T
```

Source: http://gembundler.com/