# 504 : Gateway Time-out Error when accessing rails app on Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

I'm using 
Ruby 2.1.1
Rails 4.1.0
Unicorn

It's set up on a digital ocean droplet

And this is the error I found on

```
I, [2013-12-20T02:08:31.304781 #4461]  INFO -- : listening on addr=127.0.0.1:8080 fd=3
I, [2013-12-20T02:08:31.305210 #4461]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2013-12-20T02:08:31.305476 #4461]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2013-12-20T02:08:31.305785 #4461]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2013-12-20T02:08:31.308891 #4463]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=4463
/home/rails/config/boot.rb:4:in `require': no such file to load -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /home/rails/config/boot.rb:4
    from /home/rails/config/application.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/rails/config/application.rb:1
    from /home/rails/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
    from /home/rails/config/environment.rb:2
    from config.ru:4:in `require'
    from config.ru:4
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:1:in `new'
    from config.ru:1
```

The contents of bootfile.rb seem to be default one that all rails applications have.

The rails app works perfectly on Web Brick on development.

Comment: Seems like your server is missing the bundler gem?

Comment: Michael, did you manage to fix this in the end? I am facing the exact same issue right now.

Comment: Any updates on this? I was able to reproduce this issue multiple times

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Do let me know if you find a solution! I managed to get the app to work on Heroku, but I'd really like to move back to Digital Ocean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be one of two issues:

1. Bundler isn't installed - In this case simply run 'gem install bundler'
2. You're using two different ruby installations or rubygems installations for your app than your development environment and the gemset for your production app doesn't include bundler.

If you're using RVM, try "rvm use 2.x.x" (or whatever version it is you're using) followed by a bundle install.

Comment: 1 - Tried this. Refer other answer.
2 - I specifed rvm use 2.1.1 on both machines followed by bundle install

Is there anything else I could do? I even tried this on a new droplet

Comment: Are you using the sudo command anywhere when you're starting your server? I remember running into a problem when my gems were installed with my non-su user but I used sudo at the time of starting my server.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [install the bundler gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417825/cannot-start-rails-server-no-such-file-to-load-bundler-setup), as this is what Rails is complaining about:

if you SSH into your server, you should type `gem bundle install` in your `/home/rails` folder. However, you may also want to verify you're using the correct version of Ruby, as mentioned by `Nikhil`

Comment: Done this!
`*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.4)
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (1.6.2, 1.5.3)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
executable-hooks (1.3.1)
gem-wrappers (1.2.4)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
psych (2.0.3)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.3, 1.4.2)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (2.1.1.0)
`

I even included bundler in my Gemfile